# AspNet Core How can I change MicrosoftAccountOptions/GoogleOptions/FacebookOptions/TwitterOptions in controller

Tags: asp.net-core

This's in Startup.cs `ConfigureServices` how I config the OAuth providers

```cs
services.AddAuthentication(options => {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddFacebook(x => {
                x.AppId = "xxx";
                x.AppSecret = "xxx";
            })
            .AddTwitter(x => {
                x.ConsumerKey = "xxx";
                x.ConsumerSecret = "xxx";
            })
            .AddGoogle(x => {
                x.ClientId = "xxx";
                x.ClientSecret = "xxx";
            })
            .AddMicrosoftAccount(x => {
                x.ClientId = "xxx";
                x.ClientSecret = "xxx";
            })
```

Then, for some requirements, I need to update AppId/AppSecret in controller action, How I can do that?

Comment: For the curious, why is this required?

Comment: One approach is to remove and replace the scheme. See https://github.com/aspnet/AuthSamples/blob/dev/samples/DynamicSchemes/README.md